# Check if two points from two calibrated cameras can be 3D Triangulated

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Currently I am using the *triangulatePoints* function from OpenCV to triangulate two 2D points from two calibrated cameras into a 3D Point.

```
cv::triangulatePoints(calibration[camera1Index].getProjectionMatrix(), calibration[camera2Index].getProjectionMatrix(), points1, points2, points4D);
```

My code uses the projection matrix of the cameras and the undistorted point for each camera to find the 3D point.

The problem is that sometimes the cameras send points that can't be correlated.

**My question is if there is any method to find the zone where a point from the first camera should be projected in the second camera and discard all the points from the second camera outside of that zone.**

I've been searching and I guess homography is the solution here but I wasn't able to find an approach for this algorithm or if there's an existing method in OpenCV for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "points that can't be correlated"? Every pair of points can be triangulated but sometimea the resulting 3D point is behind the camera. Can you post the code that you use to get points1 and points 2?

Comment: points1 and points2 are arrays containing the x and y positions for each point the cameras detected. By "points that can't be correlated" I mean when the resulting 3d point would be behind the camera. If the resulting point is behind the camera that means one of the cameras wasn't able to see it so it's not valid.

Comment: the "zone" is the epipolar line and maybe some region around it